# How to push a directory in server into a folder inside master in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have a directory on server like ~\Main_Folder\Folder1
and on my gitlab I have master branch with structure of Main_Folder
what I want to do is creating the same structure of folder in master as I have on my server.
the point is I dont know how to modify this command

```
git push origin master
```

with this command I only can copy Folder1 in main root of master which is wrong in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `Main_Folder\Folder1` in your repository, then you would need to replicate that  in your repo:

```
cd ~/Main_Folder
mkdir Main_Folder
git mv Folder1 Main_Folder/Folder1
git commit -m "add Main_Folder"
git push -u origin master
```

But yes, that would means `~/Main_Folder/Main_Folder/Folder1`, because your repo is cloned at `~/Main_Folder`

It is better to keep your repo as is, and clone it directly in the right folder on your server.

The [OP mahta 1988](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1538795/mahta-1988) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024985/how-to-push-a-directory-in-server-into-a-folder-inside-master-in-gitlab/63027952?noredirect=1#comment111711525_63027952):

> steps I did:
>
> ```
> git clone repositoryname.git 
> git add . 
> git commit -m "Initial Commit" 
> git pull --rebase 
> git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories 
> git push origin master
> ```

Comment: Hi Von, thanks for your answer.
May I ask if your suggestion is in case I am working on local git or not ?
Because what I want to do is transfering files in my local pc to my remote git repository in gitlab but I dont want to transfer those files in root of master , I want to transfer them in a specific folder in gitlab

Comment: @mahta1988 Exactly, that is why you will need to create that specific folder in your local Git repository, git mv those files here, and then add, commit and push.

Comment: Thank you @VonC , actually what I did and it worked I clone the repository from git and then push it

Comment: yes... thanks  :)
steps I did:
git clone https://repositoryname.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git pull --rebase
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git push origin master

Comment: @mahta1988 Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.